# Переход между 2d и 3d в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, 3d, 2d

я пишу простенькую игру на Unity и работаю в 2d измерении, но я хотел бы реализовать переход между 2d и 3d:
Игрок в 2d режиме входит в портал и резко игра переходит в 3d режим, отсюда вопрос: 
Возможно ли это и как это реализовать?

Comment: В Unity нет понятия "только 2D", 2D режим - это лишь перпендикулярная оси Z камера и все.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Или подгружаешь другую сцену в которой будет камера с Projection Perspective
2. или на этой же сцене делаешь переключение Orthographic на Perspective в твоей главной камере (настройка Projection)